# Are there any 4 star healing foods?

Tags: genshin-impact

I was doing some cooking today and realised that I have no 4 star healing dishes.

Most of the healing foods seem to be 3 star. When I say healing food, ones that recover HP, like this Northern Apple Stew.

[image: Northern Apple Stew]

Are there any 4 star HP recovery foods in Genshin Impact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently all recovery items are assigned a rarity of 3 or below, as you can see in the table available on the wiki [here](https://genshin-impact.fandom.com/wiki/Food#List_of_Food_Items).

It is also worth noticing that all four star dishes are atk / def booster since all potions are three star. Also, as now  there is only one five star dish: Adeptus' Temptation, whose recipe is found hidden in a chest (worry not, a side quest will actually send you there).

... which you can actually make yourself in real life with [the official recipe](https://ys.mihoyo.com/main/news/detail/14099). If you can read Chinese, that is...
Or you can go [to Mori channel](https://www.youtube.com/@morikitchen/videos) for some fan made unofficial version:P